# Different result of hash value in Microsoft Word

Tags: file, hash, ms-word

I have a Microsoft Word Document and I am trying to get its hash value, the problem is when I save again that document it will produce different hash value.

example:

The first hash value of my document is **"abc"** 
when I open the document and save it without any changes and try again to get its hash value it will produce **"def"** hash value

I tried to search the cause of it and it said that it is because of "Time Stamp", "Undo Buffer" etc.

Is there any way to produce same hash value with my document? by saving it without any changes?  Because I am creating duplicate file finder application and that is the problem that I encountered that I cannot solve.

Comment: When a user opens a document and saves it via Word, all sorts of things can change, especially if revision marking is enabled. Given that, you probably need to think beyond "exact duplicates" and think in terms of providing your user with some kind of measure of the difference between one version of a document and another.

Answer (score 1):

How about converting the document to PDF and then calculating the hash?
I mean "Save As PDF" via the usual Word menu.

The best way might be computing the hash on the text extracted from the document.
Or from your perspective even a font change is a change you want to detect?